# What is the scala 2.13 interpreter main class?

Tags: scala, sbt, scala-2.13

If I don't have the `scala` command in the PATH, or I wanted to specifically run the sbt project's scala version-- *without* using `sbt console`-- what would be the `sbt runMain` for scala 2.13?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see it in the build: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/build.sbt#L1086

"scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner"

Comment: Are you actually able to put that in a runMain?  I get a class not found.  I see it in the intellij console startup, but it isn't in the scaladocs: https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.0/scala-compiler/scala/tools/nsc/index.html

Comment: `MainGenericRunner` is in scala-compiler.jar (not scala-library.jar) so trying to `runMain` it will fail (class not found) unless the compiler JAR is on your classpath